# What's the difference between $document and $window.document in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas

I tried the following code in JSBin, the first one could get the canvas object. However, the second one cannot.

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/natavejasa/1/edit?html,js,output

```
var canvas = $window.document.getElementById('myCanvas');
```

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/yareb/1/edit?html,js,output

```
var canvas = $document.getElementById('myCanvas');
```

So I'm wondering what's the difference between `$window.document` and `$document`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`$document` is equivalent to `angular.element(window.document)` - a jqLite wrapper for `window.document`.

`$window.document` is the same as `window.document` - i.e. it is the DOM element `document`.

The following is `true`:

```
$window.document === $document[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

**$document** is an Angular service which reference to the browser's window.document object.

```
<script>
   var app = angular.module('documentExample', []);
     app.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$document', function ($scope,$document) {
              $scope.title = $document[0].title;
              $scope.windowTitle = angular.element(window.document)[0].title;
        }]);
 </script>

<div ng-app="documentExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">
   <p>$document title: <b ng-bind="title"></b></p>
   <p>window.document title: <b ng-bind="windowTitle"></b></p>
</div>
```

- $window.document is the same as window.document

Answer (score -5):

This is not different, it's like you see from level. This is not angularjs it's js, but you need remove first dollar.
As it is seen from angularjs hard to say. You need be use simple js when this be possible.
These entities are global.

Comment: Yes it is different. Read the previous answer by @New Dev